Book about a girl who meets a ghost boy, goes to magic school and meets a werewolf who wears a red cloak
I remember reading this book where a girl befriends a guy, but he turns out to be a ghost because he died a long time ago. The girl goes off to a school to learn magic and befriends another guy who turns into a werewolf? He wears a red cloak and goes on the roof to be a warning signal to other monsters. The girl changes cloak colors and she becomes more powerful. Does anyone know the name of a book like this?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?
